# How to animate my element using Anime.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, anime.js

I'm using Articulate Storyline to create some cool javascript animations...
First I need to find and select the element that I'm going to animate...
I'm using jQuery to select elements by finding their CSS class. I can find elements by pretty much any data attribute assigned to them, in this case, it's aria-label. So my selector will look something like this:

```
 $('[aria-label="my_image"]')
```

I need to take another step though. Storyline converts almost everything you put on a slide into an SVG when it gets published. It wraps the SVG with HTML DIV tag which holds our aria-label. Therefore, I actually want to apply my effects on SVG within the DIV so I select it like so:

```
 $('[aria-label="my_image"] svg')
```

Now I have my element I can use TweenLite from GreenSock or any JS animation engine to make some animations to it. For instance, the following code will find the "myElement" and pushes it to the right...

Note: "myElement" element is an image on my Storyline stage. and the code executes when a button is clicked.

```
var item = $('[aria-label="myElement"] svg')
go();
function go() {
    TweenLite.to(item, 1, {left:"63px"});
}
```

Now I want to use Anime.JS Animation Engine instead of TweenLite and I'm confused why it doesn't work? and how to make it work?

```
var item = $('[aria-label="spinner"] svg')
go();
function go() {
    var customBezier = anime({
        targets: '#item',
        translateX: 250,
        easing: [.91,-0.54,.29,1.56]
    });
}
```

I don't know how to reference my target? I've tried :

```
targets: '#item',
targets: '.item',
targets: 'item',
```

Any Idea is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Shouldn’t it just be `targets : item`? Since `item` is a variable that you declared earlier

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `'[aria-label="spinner"] svg'`?

```
function go() {
  var customBezier = anime({
    targets: '[aria-label="spinner"] svg',
    translateX: 250,
    easing: [.91,-0.54,.29,1.56]
  });
}
```

Looks to me like a CSS selector is what AnimeJS wants.

Comment: That's working David, Thank you for your quick and working answer

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the apostrophe:

```
var item = $('[aria-label="spinner"] svg')
go();
function go() {
    var customBezier = anime({
        targets: item,
        translateX: 250,
        easing: [.91,-0.54,.29,1.56]
    });
}
```

http://animejs.com/documentation/